# Call a custom document converter using Sharepoint Object Model

Tags: sharepoint

How to call a custom SharePoint converter that is activated for a specific website.

For example, the below code is used to get the GUID of that converter

foreach (SPDocumentConverter converter in converters)

```
        {

            //Console.WriteLine(converter.DisplayName);

            if (converter.ConvertFrom.ToLower().Equals("pdf") && converter.ConvertTo.ToLower().Equals("jpg"))

                pdfToJpgConverterId = converter.Id;

        }
```

and the SPFile.Convert method is used to call the converter usually. But when I am trying to call the document converter using SpFile.Convert method, its not calling it.

My custom conveter takes 2 command line arguments. How can I pass them to my converter when I called it using SharePointObject model or some other.

#### Update:

A document converter is custom executable file, which is deployed to a specific website as a feature. I want to transform the given pdf file into images by supplying the file name to the document converter using Sharepoint object model. SPFile.Convert method has an argument like "-config", which is a third parameter where we pass the required information(parameters). Can anyone help in this regard?

Answer (score 1):

You may want to consider invoking the process directly using Process.Start and passing the command line arguments.